# How can I auto-fill a form using preset values and trigger a submit in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-functional-component

I have a functional component with controlled form elements. When users fill out this form, it updates state values. When they hit submit, I run a function that reads state values and makes ajax calls.

*In addition to this*, I want a 1-click form submission feature. To reuse code, I've been trying to update the same state values behind this 1-click link, then trigger a form submission.

However, since React functional components don't support state update callbacks, I can't call the submit function without a race condition.

How can I support *both* use cases cleanly?

Here's a minimal component layout to illustrate what I have.

```
function Exhibit(props) {
  initialForm = {/* ... */};
  const [form, setForm] = useReducer((currForm, newValues) => ({...currForm, ...newValues}), initialForm);
  function oneClickSubmit() {
    setForm({
      // Preset values
    });
    submitForm();  // RACE CONDITION HERE
  }
  function submitForm() {
    // Does stuff with form
  }
  return <div>
    <form>
      {/* Fields that call setForm */}
      ...
    </form>
    <button onClick={submitForm}>Start</button>
  </div>
}
```

In a class component, this would have been cakewalk. Just update state, call `submitForm` in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can React.useEffect which will be invoked when form values in state are updated. Here you can validate the values and invoke the form submission instead of doing in the `formSubmit`.

```
function Exhibit(props) {
  initialForm = {/* ... */};

  const [form, setForm] = useReducer((currForm, newValues) => ({...currForm, ...newValues}), initialForm);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (validate(form) && form.oneClickSubmit) {
      submitForm()
    }
  }, [form]);

  function oneClickSubmit() {
    setForm({
      // Preset values,
      oneClickSubmit: true
    });
  }

  function submitForm() {
    // Does stuff with form
  }

  return <div>
    <form>
      {/* Fields that call setForm */}
      ...
    </form>
    <button onClick={submitForm}>Start</button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I don't want to auto submit the form if the user is actively filling it out and hasn't clicked the submit button. The form may be valid when it's partially filled out. Besides, I only want to auto submit if the user invokes 1-click.

Comment: Have a flag that maintains if user has clicked one time submit button and check that flag in `useEffect`. Also make sure useEffect is invoked on flag change value as well. Updated answer above.

Comment: @Antrikshy did you get a chance to see above updated answer?

Comment: This looks promising. Do you know if there's a guarantee of the `setForm` reducer finishing before the `setIsOneClickSubmit` state update? Or are you relying on `validate(form)`? IF you are, there's another edge case. The user could fill out the form partially until its valid, change their mind, and click the one-click option. If order isn't guaranteed, it could submit their partial form instead  of my preset.

Comment: In that case merge the form state and isOneClickSubmit  submit together. Meaning, in the form object have a key called isOneClickSubmit and then you will only be updating one state. Hence no issue of guarantee @Antrikshy

Comment: @Antrikshy did you get a chance to see above updated answer?

Comment: I like this idea, but got side tracked, so I have yet to validate it. Will come back when I do, and maybe also update your answer with the solution that worked.

Comment: This works well! I updated the answer to incorporate the auto-submit-key-inside-the-form suggestions from your comments. I also had an optional use case to save this form's state in local storage, and this solution makes it prone to accidentally auto-submitting when the form is restored from local storage. But beggars can't be choosers, and I had to put in some elbow grease to delete the key from the form before saving it.